# Add or removing a class to a element in a child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've recently hit a wall with vue. Currently we three components `Parent.vue` `ChildOne.vue` and `ChildTwo.vue`. Parent Passes some object data (from a state) to the `ChildOne` component.

The `ChildOne`component has the `ChildTwo` component as a custom element. On that custom element `<ChildTwo></ChildTwo>` we have a `v-for` loop that loops through the data and the `ChildTwo` component is just for html formatting the data.

What I want to is on a click add a custom class `.selected` to a div and remove it from the other div if selected, much like my example here.
https://codepen.io/david-wh/pen/gOrzQVR

Here is a sandbox of the full app I'm using:
https://codesandbox.io/s/onclick-forked-tkkre

**Parent**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ChildOne :container-slot-data="ObjectData"></ChildOne>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildOne from "./childComponentOne.vue";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    ChildOne
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ObjectData: [
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "foo",
          type: "aug",
          subType: "1"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          name: "bar",
          type: "aug",
          subType: "2"
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          name: "foobar",
          type: "gear",
          subType: "6"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

**ChildOne**

```
<template>
  <div class="Testing">
    <ChildTwo v-for="(itemData, index) in containerSlotData" :key="index" :item-data="itemData"></ChildTwo>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildTwo from "./childComponentTwo.vue";
export default {
  name: "ChildOne",
  components: {
    ChildTwo
  },
  data() {
    return {
      current: null
    };
  },

  props: {
    containerSlotData: {
      type: Array,
      default: null
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**ChildTwo**

```
<template>
  <!-- <div class="selected"> -->
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>{{ itemData.id }}</li>
      <li>{{ itemData.name }}</li>
      <li>{{ itemData.subType }}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Childtwo",
  data() {
    return { current: null };
  },

  props: {
    itemData: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is to toggle the class on the elements, I suggest:

In ChildOne add a `selectedItem` to data and set it with @click handler.

In ChildTwo add a @click hanlder that will emit `click` event to the ChildOne compontent.

You can see a working example forked from your CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/onclick-forked-rr5fl?file=/src/components/childComponentTwo.vue)

I have added `font-weight: bold` to the `.selected` class to make it visible.

Comment: Ahhh I see it's a failure to understand on my part. I'm guessing things change a bit more if you wanted to apply the class to a `<li>` element instead of the div?

Comment: yes. You could add a prop `selected` which will be boolean and then in `ChildTwo` use `:class` to set the class if this prop's value is true

Comment: Or you can handle it in CSS by selector `.selected li#some_specific_id_or_class` if you want to just style for example the `<li>` that stores `itemData.name`